# Re-writing UPDATE query without IN using INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

I have a query:

```
UPDATE table_1 set field_1 = 1 where field_2 IN 
(SELECT field_2 from table_2 where field_3 = 1)
```

However this takes a LONG time with a large database (>2000ms). Is there anway to re-write this query using JOINs to get away from using IN?

NOTE: There are indexes on field_1, and field_3 however it doesn't help the query. This is using MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE table_1, table_2
    SET table_1.field_1 = 1
    WHERE table_1.field_2 = table_2.field_2
        AND table_2.field_3 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The required code is below,

```
UPDATE t1 
set field_1 = 1 
from table_1 t1
join table_2 t2
    on t1.field_2 = t2.field_2
where t2.field_3 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested this code.

```
UPDATE table_1 t1 
 INNER JOIN table_2 t2 
  SET t1.field_1 = 1
WHERE t1.field_2 = t2.field_2
AND t2.field_3 = 1;
```

Cheers!